# Bad estimates for 'dbcc checkdb with estimateonly'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to compute the estimated tempdb space needed to run `CHECKDB` on one of our largest databases of size 7TB using the command `DBCC CHECKDB WITH ESTIMATEONLY`. The estimates came out to be `1.7 TB`, but with actual command `DBCC CHECKDB` itself used `221 GB`

I didn't get why the estimates are showing as 8x times than the actual and how to take this estimates into consideration to provision the appropriate tempdb space?

```
DBCC results for 'database_01'.
Estimated TEMPDB space (in KB) needed for CHECKDB on database database_01 = 1.
Estimated TEMPDB space (in KB) needed for CHECKDB on database database_01 = 1869994340.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Server Version: `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17) (KB5001092) - 13.0.5888.11 (X64)`